# Centering a Background Image and Auto Layout Fiasco

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a background image whose width is 768 pixels as shown below.  And I have several smaller images that need to be placed at the positions exactly where they are.  For example, the blue one needs to be positioned at 40, 120.

[image]

A problem will occur when the user changes the device orientation to Landscape.  The background image is positioned at the center (Editor > Align > Horizontal Center in Container).  So the background image is laid out horizontally at the center.  The system automatically sets the x-coordinate of the blue image to 40, rather than 40 pixels from the edge of the the background image.  So little guys are misplaced.  (Expected positions are shown in white.)

[image]

So what can I do to lay out the little guys in relation to the position of the background image?  I've done many things like selecting the background picture and a respective little guy and choosing Editor > Pin > Horizontal Spacing.  Nothing works.  Is it possible to keep relative locations regardless of the device orientation in this case?  Or should I just go without 'Auto Layout'?  The 2nd best choice is not to position the background picture.  But the app won't look good when the user changes the orientation to Landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

embed the little ones in the background image **(embed all in a container UIView!)**

coordinates are always relative to the outer container

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  If I put the little guys in a UIScrollView group, they can't be positioned at the center as a whole.  If I put them in a UIView group, that will be worse.

Comment: I dont even know a scrollview group :D it looks from the screenshot like you want to move all views as one. so why not have ONE fixed size view (which is centered but not resiazble) which contains the rest?

Answer (score 0):

I got it somehow by putting them in a UIScrollView group and then moving them as a whole like the following.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    uiscrollview1.Frame=CGRectMake(uiscrollview1.frame.origin.x, uiscrollview1.frame.origin.y, uiscrollview1.frame.size.width, uiscrollview1.frame.size.height);
}
else
{
    uiscrollview1.Frame=CGRectMake(uiscrollview1.frame.origin.x+128, uiscrollview1.frame.origin.y, uiscrollview1.frame.size.width, uiscrollview1.frame.size.height);
}
}
```

That's so far the best result.